# why should I convert my 32 bit application to 64 bit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Can someone give me a reason, I should convert my 32 bit application to 64 bit please. Normally I convert them to 64 for server and then publish them.

But I didn't really seen any difference.

Comment: Negative Votes and answering question, now I can't even delete it. Well Done.

Comment: wtf how is that question unconstructive? This site is getting ridiculous.

Comment: I don't see why this is unconstructive either. `We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.` How is 32 bit vs 64 bit *not supported by facts*?

Comment: Methinks we need an intervention.

Comment: "Can someone give me a reason" might sound a bit "impertinent" and 34 bit vs. 64 bit is something that can easily be googled so the question doesn't show much effort. But that doesn't fall under the definition of "not constructive". So, well... +1 to ease the pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

64 bit applications can address more than 2GB or memory.

Comment: I think it's at least 2GB per process in Windows (4GB with IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE) and with some fiddling +- 3GB in Linux - 4GB is the memory the processor can physically address.

Comment: 2 gig is indeed the limit on 32 bit apps not 4

Answer (score 0):

Like @SLaks already said: 64 bit applications can address more than 2-3GB of RAM (minus the amount required for the runtime).

64 bit applications also can make full use of a 64 bit CPU's 64 bit bandwidth; meaning it can perform faster when working on lots of data that require 64 bit instead of 32 bit or less.
Most 32 bit apps perform faster than 64 bit ones, though.

64 bit applications can also access 32 bit processes, whereas the other way around is not true. I discovered this, when I tried to write an app that behaves similarly to the *Task Manager* and had to make it 64 bit in order to access more processes.

More information on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64_bit#32-bit_vs_64-bit).

Comment: a lot of the time you will find the 32 bit version actually performs quicker in .net

Comment: @JohnNicholas: The .Net has two very different JITters for 32-bit vs. 64-bit.  They have different strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: idd and you will often find ... look at discussions of any cpu ... that 32 bit versions are actually quicker a lot of the time. go test it yourself, you would be surprised - i was.

Comment: Encoders, decoders or encryption software are the most likely to benefit from switching from 32 bit to 64 bit.